# How to catch global keyPress events in Ember

Tags: keyboard, ember.js

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, but: How do I respond to a keypress event *anywhere* on the page?

For example, say I had a video player and I wanted to pause it if a user pressed the spacebar at any point.  Or, I'm writing a game and want the arrow keys to direct a character, without regard for specific views or subviews.

Defining `App.ApplicationView = Ember.View.create({ keyPress: whatever })` doesn't seem to work.  I would have thought that all keypress events would bubble up to that.

I guess what I want to do is:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    alert('You pressed a key!');
});
```

Except through Ember.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are looking for a global keypress your code example above is probably the best solution. The ember application is attached to the body (or a root element you've defined) and would require some sort of focus on the view. For example you could do:

```
App.ApplicationView = Em.View.extend({
  keyUp: function(){
    alert(1);
  }
});
```

This will work, but the application view or a child will need to have focus. This is useful, for example, if you wanted to capture a key event of all input fields.

Comment: when a child view has focus my application level events are lost, still searching for the best Ember way to do this.